# How to set the length adjustment bytes mentioned in the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder class

Tags: netty

From the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`'s documentation, it allow user to decode the header field `Header 1` . So which encoder class allow user to define such header field?

```
* This is an advanced example that shows the case where there is an extra
 * header between the length field and the message body.  You have to specify a
 * positive <tt>lengthAdjustment</tt> so that the decoder counts the extra
 * header into the frame length calculation.
 * <pre>
 * lengthFieldOffset   = 0
 * lengthFieldLength   = 3
 * <b>lengthAdjustment</b>    = <b>2</b> (= the length of Header 1)
 * initialBytesToStrip = 0
 *
 * BEFORE DECODE (17 bytes)                      AFTER DECODE (17 bytes)
 * +----------+----------+----------------+      +----------+----------+----------------+
 * |  Length  | Header 1 | Actual Content |----->|  Length  | Header 1 | Actual Content |
 * | 0x00000C |  0xCAFE  | "HELLO, WORLD" |      | 0x00000C |  0xCAFE  | "HELLO, WORLD" |
 * +----------+----------+----------------+      +----------+----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Netty itself doesn't include such an encoder but you should easily be able to write your own and just write bytes to the ByteBuf before you write it down the pipeline.